# https to https problem - 404 and can't login

Tags: login, 404-error, ssl, https, http

Really hope someone can help with a problem I’ve been trying to fix for several hours.

Site in question is: http://www.lisasell.co.uk/

Firstly, content is failing to load due to them being served from https://www.lisasell.co.uk/, which is no longer an option after I disabled SSL from Cloudflare. I have changed the nameservers back to their defaults, so the site isn’t going through Cloudflare any more.

Also, posts point to their https:// versions from the homepage, not http://. Worst still, I can not login!

http://www.lisasell.co.uk/wp-login.php works, but when I try to login, it redirects to https://www.lisasell.co.uk/wp-login.php with “The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server” message.

Changing **siteurl** and **home** in the database to http:// hasn't fixed it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I’m truly stuck and can’t fix this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress database is still holding some data (post content, image urls etc) in it's database.

You need to go into your database and change the url references to the non-ssl as well. I suggest NOT doing this through phpmyadmin though as it will cause some problems.

Go get this tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Upload the contents of the zipped file into a new directory in your www/ folder. (I usually rename the search and replace folder to SRDB.)
Now navigate to your site with the SRDB at the end. (www.example.com/SRDB)and the top two lines you'll see a search field and a replace field. (if you get a db connection error here, double check the wp-config to ensure that it has the right credentials).

In the search place your old site address with ssl: https://www.example.com
in the replace field place your new url without ssl http://www.example.com/
hit live live run. 
ONLY do this after ensuring you're on your new url and that it's loaded into your new database AND you've backed up your db just in case.
This should fix your problems!